# How can I prevent "method only to call other method" in my code?

Tags: oop, architecture, abstract-class

Let's assume I wrote a class `Authentication` that provides methods for registering users and signing them in.
Of course I need another class `DB` that will run the actual database statements and retrieve the data.

When importing `Authentication` in another application to make use of it, I would call its method `signUpUser()` that will sign up a user.
Now this method will run essentially a method with the same name and purpose that you would expect from `Authentication.signUpUser()` but actually doing the database statements in `DB`.

Is there any way of preventing this "methods in this class do nothing but calling another methods" approach? Should I event prevent such wrapper functions? What are good habits here and why?